Tikz calc distance modifier erros on rotated lines in matrix
I want to illustrate how to group together certain terms in an infinite table. So far I have made this:

I also want to group a₂b₃ with a₃b₂, and make another group for a₃b₃. So far i have made the lines with dotted ends based on other Tex stack exchange answers here and here. The above example was made using the following code:
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{tikz} 
\usetikzlibrary{positioning, fit, matrix, decorations.pathreplacing, calc}

\tikzset{%
  rect/.style n args={4}{
        draw=none,
        rectangle,
        append after command={
            \pgfextra{%
                \pgfkeysgetvalue{/pgf/outer xsep}{\oxsep}
                \pgfkeysgetvalue{/pgf/outer ysep}{\oysep}
                \def\arg@one{#1}
                \def\arg@two{#2}
                \def\arg@three{#3}
                \def\arg@four{#4}
                \begin{pgfinterruptpath}
                    \ifx\\#1\\\else
                        \draw[draw,#1] ([xshift=-\oxsep,yshift=+\pgflinewidth]\tikzlastnode.south east) edge[decorate] ([xshift=-\oxsep,yshift=0\ifx\arg@two\@empty-\pgflinewidth\fi]\tikzlastnode.north east);
                    \fi\ifx\\#2\\\else
                        \draw[draw,#2] ([xshift=-\pgflinewidth,yshift=-\oysep]\tikzlastnode.north east) edge[decorate] ([xshift=0\ifx\arg@three\@empty+\pgflinewidth\fi,yshift=-\oysep]\tikzlastnode.north west);
                    \fi\ifx\\#3\\\else
                        \draw[draw,#3] ([xshift=\oxsep,yshift=0-\pgflinewidth]\tikzlastnode.north west) edge[decorate] ([xshift=\oxsep,yshift=0\ifx\arg@four\@empty+\pgflinewidth\fi]\tikzlastnode.south west);
                    \fi\ifx\\#4\\\else
                        \draw[draw,#4] ([xshift=0+\pgflinewidth,yshift=\oysep]\tikzlastnode.south west) edge[decorate] ([xshift=0\ifx\arg@one\@empty-\pgflinewidth\fi,yshift=\oysep]\tikzlastnode.south east);
                    \fi
                \end{pgfinterruptpath}
            }
        }
    },
    dotted ends/.style={
        decoration={
            show path construction,
            lineto code={
                \draw[dashed,#1] (\tikzinputsegmentfirst) --($(\tikzinputsegmentfirst)!-.2!(\tikzinputsegmentlast)$);,
                \draw (\tikzinputsegmentfirst) -- (\tikzinputsegmentlast);,
                \draw[dashed,#1] (\tikzinputsegmentlast) -- ($(\tikzinputsegmentlast)!-.2!(\tikzinputsegmentfirst)$);,
            }
        },
        decorate
    },
}



\begin{document}

\begin{center}    
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \matrix[
            matrix of nodes,
            inner sep=20pt,
            row sep=2mm,
            column sep=2mm,
            every node/.style={
                circle,
                inner sep=0pt,
                align=center,
                text width=3em,
                text height=0.8em,
                text depth=0.2em,
            }] (m) {
                $a_0b_0$ & $a_0b_1$ & $a_0b_2$ & $a_0b_3$ & $\cdots$ \\
                $a_1b_0$ & $a_1b_1$ & $a_1b_2$ & $a_1b_3$ & $\cdots$ \\
                $a_2b_0$ & $a_2b_1$ & $a_2b_2$ & $a_2b_3$ & $\cdots$ \\
                $a_3b_0$ & $a_3b_1$ & $a_3b_2$ & $a_3b_3$ & $\cdots$ \\
                $\vdots$ & $\vdots$ & $\vdots$ & $\vdots$ & $\ddots$ \\
            };
            \node[
                inner sep=0pt,
                draw=blue,
                thick,
                rounded corners=1.2em,
                rotate fit=-45,
                fit={(m-1-1) (m-1-1)}
            ] {};
            \node[
                inner sep=0pt,
                draw=blue,
                thick,
                rounded corners=1.2em,
                rotate fit=-45,
                fit={(m-1-2) (m-2-1)}
            ] {};
            \node[
                inner sep=0pt,
                draw=blue,
                thick,
                rounded corners=1.2em,
                rotate fit=-45,
                fit={(m-1-3) (m-3-1)}
            ] {};
            \node[
                inner sep=0pt,
                draw=blue,
                thick,
                rounded corners=1.2em,
                rotate fit=-45,
                fit={(m-1-4) (m-4-1)}
            ] {};
            \node[
                inner sep=0pt,
                rotate fit=-45,
                fit={(m-2-4) (m-4-2)},
                rect={thick, blue, dotted ends={thick}}{}{thick, blue, dotted ends={thick}}{}
            ] {};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}

\end{document}

However, when applying the dotted-ends style to the 2 last groups results in shorter dashed lines in the end:

I have attempted to fix this by replacing ($(\tikzinputsegmentfirst)!-.2!(\tikzinputsegmentlast)$) with ($(\tikzinputsegmentfirst)!-1cm!(\tikzinputsegmentlast)$). However, this has resulted in some errors, and the lines now look like this:

How do I fix this?

Unrelated: Instead of matrix of nodes, you can use matrix of math nodes and then remove the $s from the matrix entries.

Thank you, that is good to know.

While decorations are very powerful, I think you can get away here with a specific arrow tip specification.
Code
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix, fit, arrows.meta}
\begin{document}
\tikz[
  Fit Line/.style={draw=blue, thick},
  Fit Node/.style={inner sep=+0pt, rotate fit=45, fit={#1}},
  Fit/.style={Fit Line, Fit Node={#1}, rounded corners=+1.2em},
  % the style dashed is 3pt on and 3pt off
  % the arrow tip Butt Cap needs compensation for some internal corrections
  Dashed Butt/.tip={Butt Cap[length=+3pt +-.75, sep=+3pt +.75]},
  Dashed/.tip={. _[sep=+3pt +.75] Dashed Butt[] Dashed Butt[] Dashed Butt[sep=+0pt]}
] \matrix[
    /utils/exec=\newcommand*\ab{a_{\inteval{\pgfmatrixcurrentrow-1}}%
                                b_{\inteval{\pgfmatrixcurrentcolumn-1}}},
    row sep=+.5em, column sep=+.5em, matrix of math nodes,
    every node/.style={
      shape=circle, inner sep=+.25em, align=center,
      text width=+2.5em, text height=+.8em, text depth=+.2em},
  ](m){
   \ab   &  \ab   &  \ab   &  \ab   & \cdots \\
   \ab   &  \ab   &  \ab   &  \ab   & \cdots \\
   \ab   &  \ab   &  \ab   &  \ab   & \cdots \\
   \ab   &  \ab   &  \ab   &  \ab   & \cdots \\
  \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots \\
} node foreach \i in {1, ..., 4} [Fit=(m-1-\i)(m-\i-1)]{}
  foreach \i in {1, ..., 3}{
    (m-5-\i.north) edge[Fit Line, Dashed-Dashed] (m-\i-5.west)
    (m-5-\i.east)  edge[Fit Line, Dashed-Dashed] (m-\i-5.south)
  };
\end{document}

Output


This ought to be a case for nicematrix … but this question is more about the TikZ side of things anyway.
